# all files are send, except images taken by camera on mobile

Tags: javascript, php

Im new in to webdevelopment,
I have a contact form that in principal works. If I select files through folder selection (.jpg, .jpeg, .png) there is no problem with sending the images to reciever.

The problem pops up when using mobile,

If the user selects the camera function to make a photo to be send, This image is not send.

My js validation checks on size and file type before sending and blocks the send if there is something wrong.

Wierd thing is: Sometimes, I mean sometimes, on a newer phone, the created photo is send the first time after filling the contact form in, if the same user, with the same phone, fill the form in for a second time, the image is not send.

sorry comments are Dutch
HTML

```
 <div class="file-upload-container">

                            <!-- File Upload 1 -->
                            <label for="fileUpload1" data-lang="contact-form-11">Bestand 1:</label>
                            <input type="file" id="fileUpload1" name="fileUpload1" capture="environment"
                                accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx">
                            <span id="fileUpload1Name"></span> <!-- Span to display the uploaded file name -->

                            <!-- File Upload 2 -->
                            <label for="fileUpload2" data-lang="contact-form-12">Bestand 2:</label>
                            <input type="file" id="fileUpload2" name="fileUpload2" capture="environment"
                                accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx">
                            <span id="fileUpload2Name"></span> <!-- Span to display the uploaded file name -->
                        </div>
```

JS validation

```
function validateContactForm() {
    let naam = document.getElementById("name").value;
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let bericht = document.getElementById("message").value;
    let contactReasons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="contact_reason"]');
    let isValid = true;
    let errorMessage = '';

    // Vorige foutmeldingen wissen
    document.getElementById("formInputErrorDisplay").innerHTML = '';

    // Naam validatie
    if (naam.trim() === "") {
        errorMessage += getErrorMessage("naamRequired") + "<br>";
        isValid = false;
    }

    // E-mail validatie
    let emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
        errorMessage += getErrorMessage("invalidEmail") + "<br>";
        isValid = false;
    }

    // Bericht validatie
    if (bericht.trim().length < 100 || bericht.trim().length > 2500) {
        errorMessage += getErrorMessage("messageLength") + "<br>";
        isValid = false;
    }

    // Radio buttons validatie
let isReasonSelected = Array.from(contactReasons).some(radio => radio.checked);
if (!isReasonSelected) {
    errorMessage += getErrorMessage("reasonRequired") + "<br>";
    isValid = false;
}


     // Bestanden validatie
     let bestandsGrootteLimiet = 5242880; // 5MB
     for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
         let fileUpload = document.getElementById(`fileUpload${i}`);
         if (fileUpload && fileUpload.files.length > 0) {
             let file = fileUpload.files[0];
             if (file.size > bestandsGrootteLimiet) {
                 errorMessage += getErrorMessage("fileTooLarge", {i}) + "<br>";
                 isValid = false;
             }
             if (!['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'].includes(file.type)) {
                 errorMessage += getErrorMessage("invalidFileType", { i }) + "<br>";
                 isValid = false;
                 }
                 }
                 }


       
                 

    // Foutmeldingen weergeven in het div-element
if (!isValid) {
    document.getElementById("formInputErrorDisplay").innerHTML = errorMessage;
}

return isValid;
}

// Event listener toevoegen aan het formulier
document.getElementById("contact_form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
if (!validateContactForm()) {
event.preventDefault();
}
});
```

PHP

```
 // Bestandsverwerking en -upload
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
            $fileInputName = "fileUpload" . $i;
            if (isset($_FILES[$fileInputName]) && $_FILES[$fileInputName]['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                // Bestandstype en -grootte validatie
                $allowedTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'];
                $maxSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB
                $fileType = $_FILES[$fileInputName]['type'];
                $fileSize = $_FILES[$fileInputName]['size'];

                if (!in_array($fileType, $allowedTypes) || $fileSize > $maxSize) {
                    echo "Ongeldig bestandstype of bestandsgrootte voor bestand $i.<br>";
                    continue;
                }

                // Generate unique file name to prevent duplicates
                $fileExt = pathinfo($_FILES[$fileInputName]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $newFileName = uniqid("upload_", true) . '.' . $fileExt;
                $target_dir = "../../../back-end/uploads/";
                $target_file = $target_dir . $newFileName;

                // Bestandsupload
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileInputName]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    $bestanden[] = $target_file;
                    // Logboekbericht
                    $logMessage = "[" . date("d-m-Y H:i:s") . "] Bestand ge&#1043;&#1112;pload: " . $newFileName .
                                  " door " . $email . 
                                  ", Grootte: " . filesize($target_file) . " bytes\n";
                    writeToLog($logMessage, $email);
                } else {
                    echo "Er was een probleem met het uploaden van bestand $i.<br>";
                }
            }
        }
```

as a mailer I use the latest version of PHPmailer.

What am I missing?

I do not know where to go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential issue could be the high image resolution typical of mobile phones. This might be problematic, as PHP emails are often subject to a size limit defined in the PHP configuration. It's advisable to review the logs for insights. If the file sizes are too large, consider increasing the `upload_max_filesize` setting in the `php.ini` file. Additionally, timeouts or interruptions during the upload process can be a concern, and these, too, should be evident in the logs.

The `capture` attribute, with its different values (`user` or `environment`), merits attention as well.

While various factors could be at play, the most effective initial step is to thoroughly examine and interpret the logs.

UPDATE:

Also, before sending the image, you can even compress the images to smaller format and send the compressed version, but it depends on you what you want to achieve with your code.

Comment: While this is correct too, would it not make sense to compress the image since some photos could be 5-6 MB depending on the phone?

Comment: Image compression is another option. It all depends on what he wants. If he wants to send raw images, it can be 15MB per image. It is already a matter of the need of the project.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll add compression and will change the php.ini and will search the logs. Images that are send do not need to be the raw image, just a compression is fine for this function. Awesome. Thanks! I'll report back when I tried all of this.

Comment: SORTED! It was indeed the upload_max_filesize! Thanks a million. Would never thought of this, now I know that excists!